# bug xelatex after ubuntu update

Tags: xetex, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 20.4. After an update, i got several messages of error by xelatex like :

`File` biblatex.sty' not found. ^^M`

```
No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `french'(polyglossia) I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead
```

It must not be a problem with the preamble because it worked perfecly fine before. The update has likely disturbed the program. Any idea how I can solve that ?

Comment: ```File `biblatex.sty' not found.``` suggests that your TeX system is not a full installation with all packages. If you installed your system via `apt`/`apt-get` you may have to install additional packages via that route as well. For `biblatex` you probably want `apt install texlive-bibtex-extra biber`. For French `apt install texlive-lang-french`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine for 'apt install texlive-lang-french' and i ran 'sudo apt install texlive-full'. I have no more problem with language but the commands I create don't work. I tried '\newcommand{\ssi}{si et seulement si\xspace} and I get two messages : (1) missing number inserted ^^|^^|\item ; (2) illegal mesure of unit ^^|^^|\item

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to say anything useful about those errors without having seen a complete example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces these errors.

Comment: It's ok. I have a document where I don't have this problem anymore and one where I get the message of error but the command works anyway. I'll try to solve this by myself first. Thanks anyway